# Sitecore Call Check-List Data in Parameter Template

Tags: sitecore, datasource

I have a sublayout assigned "Parameter Template". In the parameter templates, there are some fields such as single-text, rich-text and check-list types. There is no problem when I call the single and rich-text fields in code-behind. But, I don't know how to call the list in the check-list field.

I'd like to get only selected items' information when the sublayout is added.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly read this on parameter templates

https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/martina-welander-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/07/improving-the-page-editor-experience-part-1-uses-for-parameters.aspx

Then it's useful to setup a base class to handle data sources and parameter templates. You could write your own base class based on this:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sub_Layout_Parameter_Helper.aspx

When you access the parameter values from the sublayout they will be raw values and in your case pipe delimited guids.

This is how to get the value of a parameter:

```csharp
 var sublayout = this.Parent as Sublayout;

 var parameters = sublayout.Parameters;

 var collection = WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(parameters);

 string images = collection["Images"];
```

The variable images will contain guids - you'll have to use Getitem() on these to retrieve the actual items selected by splitting the string like this:

```csharp
var selectedItems = images.split('|');
List<Item> result = new List<Item>();

foreach (var itemId in selectedItems)
{
  Guid id = Guid.Empty;
  if (Guid.TryParse(itemId, out id))
  {
    var found = db.GetItem(new ID(id));
    if (found != null)
    {
      result.Add(found);
    }
  }
}
```

The list above will now have the selected items specified on the sublayout

Answer (score 0):

The Checklist field type will only store the selected items information, I believe.

You could cast the field to a MultilistField, and then call GetItems() on it. That should give you back the list of selected items.